# Creating a new frame button in Tkinter (without __innit__)

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

I am attempting to add a button to this frame (seen in the second last paragraph of code) on Python Tkinter once the **countdown** completes. At this stage, the button will show up but won't execute to the next frame (defined earlier, code not shown, as WorkoutsPage). I will appreciate any help.. Thanks

```
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Frame.configure(self)
        tk.Label(self, text="SQUATS", bg = '#44d7b6', width=50, height=2, font=('PT Sans', 18, "bold"), foreground = 'white').pack(side="top", fill='x', pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", font=('PT Sans', 12, "bold"), 
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(WorkoutsPage)).pack()
        tk.Label(self, text="").pack()
        ## Creates a blank text line
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="")
        ## Creates the countdown as a label
        self.label.pack()
        ## The above code can be used to make the countdown look different (for TK)
        self.remaining = 0
        ## Defines '0' as the last number of the count down
        self.countdown(8)
        ## Defines the countdown to '5' seconds

    def countdown(self, remaining = None):
            if remaining is not None:
                ## Defines what the countdown will do if the time is not finished
                    self.remaining = remaining
                    ## Displays time left

            if self.remaining <= 0:
                self.label.configure(text="Workout Completed!")
                tk.Label(self, text="You have been awarded 10 points for completing Squats!").pack()
                ## As the countdown hits '0' the label will be configured to display the above.
                tk.Button(self, text="Finish Workout", font=('PT Sans', 12, "bold"), 
                     command=lambda: master.switch_frame(WorkoutsPage)).pack()
        
            else:
                self.label.configure(text="%d" % self.remaining + " Seconds Left!", font=('PT Sans', 14, "bold"))
                ## Displays the format of the countdown
                self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
                ## Sets the number displayed to be (value -1)
                self.after(1000, self.countdown)
                ## Sets the time on countdown to change after 1 second
```

Comment: What happens when you click the button? You tell us what it doesn't do but haven't said what it does.

Comment: I'm guessing something along the lines of "NameError: 'master' is not defined"?  The similar "QUIT" button presumably works, because `master` was a parameter to the method containing its creation - but you didn't save that value anywhere for future use in other methods.